# SWI Prolog maximize function appears to not work

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd

I'm new to prolog and I'm using swi-prolog on ubuntu to learn. I'm using the `clpfd` module to solve a worker/product allocation problem. 
The problem is stated in [this](http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/downloads/CPDC2003.pdf) paper on page 7.
Here is what I have so far from that paper.

```
solver(Sol) :- 
   Sol = [A,B,C,D],
   [A,B,C,D] ins 1..4,
   all_distinct(Sol),
   element(A,[7,1,3,4],A1),
   element(B,[8,2,5,1],B1),
   element(C,[4,3,7,2],C1),
   element(D,[3,1,6,3],D1),
   A1 + B1 + C1 + D1 #= E,
   maximize(E,Sol),
   label(Sol).
```

I'm unable to get `maximize` to work. It throws an error

```
ERROR: solver/1: Undefined procedure: maximize/2
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         maximize/3
```

Could someone point out why the `maximize` function isn't working as expected or how I should be framing it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, maximization is available as a `labeling/2` option. Replace the `maximize/2` and `label/1` goals by:

`labeling([max(E)], Sol]`

On backtracking, you get solutions in decreasing order of `E`.

Comment: s(X): just utilized the `min(Expr)` today. I dig that it is complete